# Get Logo (image) in menudrawer android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to place an image at the bottom of my menudrawer (google menu), but it doesn't work. I have researched the whole internet and tried everything I can imagine (in the java files and also in the xml files). It still doesn't work.
There is an example at the image below (red border):

[image: INSPIRATION APP]

The image below is my App with menudrawer:

[image: MY APP]

I will appreciate any help.

---

Like I said before I want to get an image at the bottom of my menudrawer like the app above.

There are a few files related to the menu and in the **activity_main.xml** you got all elements (like the list items) of the whole menu. So I tried to place an *imageview* in the **activity_main.xml** but that does not work. From here I am stuck I really don't know how to do this. Thanks for your help.

Here is the code of **activity_main.xml** with the *imageview* that I have placed:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/black_overlay"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"/>

<ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:background="@drawable/solaylogo"
    android:maxWidth="30dp"
    android:maxHeight="10dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The Java code below is related to this xml file:

```
package nl.vitaminen.solay;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import nl.vitaminen.solay.R;
import nl.vitaminen.solay.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import nl.vitaminen.solay.model.NavDrawerItem;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.array;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.drawable;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.id;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.layout;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.menu;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.string;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
boolean security = false;
boolean power = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Berichten
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Phone
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // About
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Settings
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));


    // EXAMPLE: navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            //getActionBar().show();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            //getActionBar().hide();

        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList) && onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

    hideMenuItems(menu, !drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void hideMenuItems(Menu menu, Boolean visible){
    for(int i =0; i< menu.size(); i++){
        menu.getItem(i).setVisible(visible);
    }
}
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new BerichtenFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        //fragment = new PhoneFragment();
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+31882002555"));
        startActivity(call);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new AboutFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // your action...

        if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else{
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}

}
```

---

### The codes below are related too to the menudrawer:

The code below is from **NavDrawerListAdapter.java**:

```
package nl.vitaminen.solay.adapter;

import nl.vitaminen.solay.R;
import nl.vitaminen.solay.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.id;
//import nl.vitaminen.solay.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

I know that the xml and java files below are not important, because this is only for the list items and not the whole menu. The reason I place this is that you maybe need it, too resolve the problem.

--

The code below is from **NavDrawerItem.java** :

```
package nl.vitaminen.solay.model;

public class NavDrawerItem {

private String title;
private int icon;
private String count = "0";
// boolean to set visiblity of the counter
private boolean isCounterVisible = false;

public NavDrawerItem(){}

public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon){
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon, boolean isCounterVisible, String count){
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
    this.count = count;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}

public int getIcon(){
    return this.icon;
}

public String getCount(){
    return this.count;
}

public boolean getCounterVisibility(){
    return this.isCounterVisible;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public void setIcon(int icon){
    this.icon = icon;
}

public void setCount(String count){
    this.count = count;
}

public void setCounterVisibility(boolean isCounterVisible){
    this.isCounterVisible = isCounterVisible;
}
}
```

and the final code below is related to the **NavDrawerListAdapter.java**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for taking the time to resolve my problem. I hope that this is enough information for you.

Comment: *[...]* ***but it doesn't work*** : What doesn't work? Why? What have you tried to solve the problem? Why it didn't work? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead? What code did you try? Is there any exception being thrown? If yes, can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem, I just changed in **activity_main.xml** the background of my listview as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@color/black_overlay"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
android:background="@drawable/navigation_image_below"/> <!-- This is the line
 I changed -->

<ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:background="@drawable/solaylogo"
android:maxWidth="30dp"
android:maxHeight="10dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The image below is the **navigation_image_below.png**

[image]

I hope this is the good solution for this problem. Probably not, because if your screen resolution is more or less your image will be stretched.

I will appreciate if someone has another solution.